# base_url error with two installation in websites

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, base-url

I have two installation of codeigniter. One at `example.com` and another at `example.com/new` but the problem I'm having is the installation at `/new` is including the header file from `example.com`. Home page of `example.com/new` is good but other pages include header file from `example.com`. I have modified the `.htaccess` file and `base_url` at `config` too.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/new [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/new/$1 [L,R=301]

Options -Indexes
Options -ExecCGI
# AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
<Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.png|*.gif)>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

`/new` is removed in the `.htaccess` file of `example.com`.

What could be the possible reason behind this? Or is it `.htaccess` file? Or routes.php file?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this `.htaccess`  for `example.com/new`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
Options -ExecCGI
# AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp 
# .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
<Files ^(*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.png|*.gif)>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

For `example.com` change only `RewriteBase` and other things will keep same

```
RewriteBase /new
```

to

```
RewriteBase /
```

`http://example.com/new` base_url, and `http://example.com` base_url

Comment: @red-cannibal, you have changed as well as `base_url` in config file?, what is error there now

Comment: it shows no error. Just the header from `example.com` is shown. I've updated the question little bit.